# React.js: How to access a component's methods within functions that passed in as props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here's my code, what I wanna do here is in Modal I got two methods that show and hide the Modal. and you can see Modal will be rendered when someone click this AddCustomer component(it's a button actually). I wanna pass two custom function handleConfirm and handleCancel. is that possible to access Modal's two method inside handleCancel and handelConfirm ? or other good way to do this stuff? thanks.

```
var Modal = require('./modal.jsx');

var AddCustomer = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function(){
    $('body').append("<div id='modal-container'></div> ");
    var modal = (
        <Modal
          ref="modal"
          confirm="OK"
          cancel="Cancel"
          onConfirm={this.handleConfirm}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}
          title="Hello, Bootstrap!">
            This is a React component powered by jQuery and Bootstrap!
        </Modal>
      );

    var modelInstance = React.render(<Modal title="test" />, document.getElementById('modal-container'));
    modelInstance.open();
  },
  handleConfirm:function(){ ??? },
  handleCancel:function(){ ??? },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="ui green button" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <i className="icon add user"></i>
        Add User
      </div>
    );
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to do it. `handleConfirm` and `handleCancel` are two callbacks passed to `Modal`, that `Modal` will call from the `onClick` handlers of respectively the OK and cancel Button

Inside `Modal` there should be something like

```
<button onClick={this.props.onConfirm}>{this.props.confirm}</button>
<button onClick={this.props.onCancel}>{this.props.cancel}</button>
```

Comment: hey thanks, but this just passed these two functions to Modal. let's say inside Modal I have a method `close:function(){ $(React.getDOMNode(this)).modal.close() }` , what should I do in handleCancel so I can call this close method ?

Comment: you should be able to call `close()` on your `modelInstance` variable, just make it a class level property so that it is visible inside the `handleConfirm` and `handleCancel` methods.